# Converting historical data frames to seperate vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, vector

I have the following data frames in R. Each one is for a different day. Can you please suggest a way to create a time series for each pair seperately, as a demonstrated below.. Thanks in advance!

```
, , 2020-10-03

            A        B        C
A       0.000000 0.957277 3.361026
B   0.957277 0.000000 8.420407
C   3.361026 8.420407 0.000000

, , 2020-10-04

             A        B        C
A       0.0000000 0.2106529 5.875128
B   0.2106529 0.0000000 8.678178
C   5.8751284 8.6781781 0.000000

, , 2020-10-05

            A         B         C
A      0.00000000 0.02922629 5.234718
B      0.02922629 0.00000000 5.109506
C      5.23471797 5.10950603 0.000000
```

from above, I want to create the following

[image]

I would appreciate your answer

Comment: Please read the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r[ tag page and in particular provide the input in reproducible form using `dput` and don't just provide input and output and assume that it is obvious how to convert one to the other but actually explain what the transformation is to go from the input to the output.  Also provide some code that goes as far as you can.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a data frame, but rather a 3D array. That being the case, we can get the lower triangle of each slice, bind the resulting vectors together and transpose:

```r
lapply(asplit(df, 3), \(x) setNames(x[lower.tri(x)], c('AB', 'AC', 'BC'))) |>
  as.data.frame(check.names = FALSE) |> t()
#>                    AB       AC       BC
#> 2020-10-03 0.95727700 3.361026 8.420407
#> 2020-10-04 0.21065290 5.875128 8.678178
#> 2020-10-05 0.02922629 5.234718 5.109506
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Reproducible data in format implied in question**

```r
df <- structure(c(0, 0.957277, 3.361026, 0.957277, 0, 8.420407, 3.361026, 
8.420407, 0, 0, 0.2106529, 5.8751284, 0.2106529, 0, 8.6781781, 
5.875128, 8.678178, 0, 0, 0.02922629, 5.23471797, 0.02922629, 
0, 5.10950603, 5.234718, 5.109506, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "C"), c("2020-10-03", "2020-10-04", 
    "2020-10-05")))

df
#> , , 2020-10-03
#> 
#>          A        B        C
#> A 0.000000 0.957277 3.361026
#> B 0.957277 0.000000 8.420407
#> C 3.361026 8.420407 0.000000
#> 
#> , , 2020-10-04
#> 
#>           A         B        C
#> A 0.0000000 0.2106529 5.875128
#> B 0.2106529 0.0000000 8.678178
#> C 5.8751284 8.6781781 0.000000
#> 
#> , , 2020-10-05
#> 
#>            A          B        C
#> A 0.00000000 0.02922629 5.234718
#> B 0.02922629 0.00000000 5.109506
#> C 5.23471797 5.10950603 0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Allan! It worked. Meanwhile, the 3 here (lapply(asplit(df, 3)) is independent of the number of the variables, I guess. Apparently, it applies to any n.. When I use it for 4 variables, I get the time series from AB to DD. I don't know why btw AA is missing but still it is fine. Appreciated!